# Spring boot update entity with same id but changed reference

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

A typical way to update an entity is:

```
val userEntity: UserEntity = userRepository.findBySomething(...)
userEntity.name = "New Name"
userRepository.save(userEntity)
```

Since the `id` of `userEntity` remains the same, spring-data-jpa will update the row instead of adding a new one.

But if we change the reference of the entity, while keeping the `id` same, it adds a new row:

```
val userEntity: UserEntity = userRepository.findBySomething(...)
val user: UserDto = userEntity.toUserDto(); //copies individual fields, including id
user.name = "New Name"
userRepository.save(user.toUserEntity()) //toUserEntity() creates a new entity object
```

Is addition of a new row in this case an expected behaviour? I briefly looked at spring boot code and looks like it just checks if the `id` is null or not, to decide whether it should `persist()` or `merge()`. Maybe some layers down it is checking the object reference to see if it is managed entity or something?

Is there a way to tell spring boot to just match the id and not the object reference, to decide whether it should update or insert a new row?

Comment: JPA (the `EntityManager`) keeps track of the persisted/attached objects.

Comment: Please show also the entity class in use. The id field should be annotated with @Id.